# How can I use an item (function) outside from UseEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is  the code in question:

```
    useEffect(() => {
    setStart(start + count);
    const fetchImages = () => {
      axios
        .get(`/api/photos?count=${count}&start=${start}`)
        .then((res) => setImages(images, ...res.data));
      fetchImages();
    };
  }, []);
```

How can I use `fetchImages` outside of the `useEffect` hook?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `fetchImages` outside of useEffect and wrap it with [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and then you can use `fetchImages` outside of `useEffect` and inside the `useEffect` as well